# Is there a log4jdbc-log4j2 alternative that is maintained?

Tags: java, logging, jdbc, log4jdbc

The [log4jdbc-log4j2](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/) library seems to be not supported anymore. The last release was in 2013. However there is a bug in the library and I need an alternative (or a bugfix).

I've googled for some alternatives but I didn't find one. Do you know any alternatives for that library?

Comment: Last commit is from June 2014. Did you report the bug?

Comment: Yes I reported the bug (https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/issues/detail?id=28). I assumed that this project is dead since the last release was in 2013. Even if the last commit was in June 2014 it seems that the project ins't maintained anymore.

Comment: If that is your reasoning for calling a project dead then most open source offerings will be dead by your definition. The idea is that someone needed something and then decided to open source it to share it with others - like you. That's a service done out of the good of someone's heart, that relies on the goodness of others to help it progress. So you have a choice: contribute or look for the next dead project.

Comment: So it is ok for an open source project to ignore open issues for more than two months? When would you consider a project to be dead? I know that every open source project starts because someone wants to share some of his work with the world but when I there isn't any visible activity for over two months and no new release for over one year I consider the project as dead. Also even if I wanted to contribute, I can only access the source readonly. Btw I suggested how it could be fixed.